# JShell zsh: unknown file attribute: 5

Tags: java, zsh, jshell

Recently I found [this](https://github.com/chartsyone/chartsy-jshell) git. But when I'm trying to execute it with `jshell -J-cp -J./lib/chartsy-jshell.jar --execution rmi:host(localhost),port(52099)` it says **zsh: unknown file attribute: 5**. So I don't understand how to run it.

Comment: use `"` around `rmi:host(localhost),port(52099)`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried and get `No ExecutionControlProvider with name 'rmi' and parameter keys: [port, host]`. If I show ECP directly with `jshell -J-cp -J./lib/chartsy-jshell.jar --execution "one.chartsy.jshell.RmiExecutionControlProvider:host(localhost),port(52099)"` it says `Expected ':' in one.chartsy.jshell.RmiExecutionControlProvider:host(localhost),port(52099)`.